# Ruby - Is it possible to alias a method to the safe navigation operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby 2.3 introduced the safe navigation operator, however I find that its syntax is too discrete an can be easy to miss when briefly scanning code. Instead I much prefer the syntax of `try` as it looks much more obvious and intentional.

So my question is in Ruby 2.3+, Is there a way to alias or monkey patch a method to the safe navigation operator `&.` to a custom method name ie. `s.fast_try(:upcase!).fast_try(:downcase)` instead of writing `s&.upcase!&.downcase`

The main idea is to attempt to improve performance over another implementation such as `try` method. No, I dont care about the minor behaviour differences between try and safe navigation operator. Also, I do not mind some obscure argument limitations if they cannot be avoided, just point them out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess you could go with something as simple as

```
class Object
  def fast_try(meth,*args,&block)
    self&.public_send(meth,*args,&block)
  end
end
```

For Example:

```
["string","STRING","pOw"].map do |s| 
  s.fast_try(:upcase!)
     .fast_try(:chars)
     .fast_try(:find, ->{"No S"}) { |a| a == "S" }
     .fast_try(:prepend, "!")
end
#=> ["!S",nil,"!No S"]
```

While your question states, *" No, I don't care about the minor behavior differences between try and safe navigation operator."*, given the fact that you have written a gem and noted the following

> Differences between FastTry and ActiveSupport#try
>
> It is not our goal to maintain any consistency with the ActiveSupport version of the try method. I do however want to maintain a simple list of the differences. Please create a PR or Issue if you find a difference that should be documented here.
>
> Nothing reported yet

I feel it prudent to mention that there are discernible, and potentially poignant, differences between the 2 here is a [Repl Spec](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/AStry-vs-and-Safe-Navigation) to show the differences and for the sake of this answer and the fact that the link might die the output of this spec is as follows:

```
ActiveSupport#try vs. Safe Navigation (&.)
  #try
    handles would be NoMethodError with nil (using #respond_to?)
    does not work on a BasicObject
    behaves like a method call
      with no method name given
        when block_given?
          yields self to a block with arity > 0
          evaluates block with arity == 0 in the context of self
        when no block_given?
          raises an ArgumentError
      with a method_name given
        a non nil object
          uses public_send for message transmission
        nil
          calls NilClass#try and returns nil
  #try!
    does not handle NoMethodError
    does not work on a BasicObject
    behaves like a method call
      with no method name given
        when block_given?
          yields self to a block with arity > 0
          evaluates block with arity == 0 in the context of self
        when no block_given?
          raises an ArgumentError
      with a method_name given
        a non nil object
          uses public_send for message transmission
        nil
          calls NilClass#try and returns nil
  &. (safe navigation)
    does not handle NoMethodError
    raises a SyntaxError with no method name given when block_given?
    raises a SyntaxError with no method name given when no block_given?
    works on a BasicObject
    does not act like a method call
      with a method_name given
        a non nil object
          &. is not called
        nil
          returns nil without a method call
```

Comment: beware: `nil&.nil? # => nil`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yep that is the way the operator works (I didn't design it) and the question was how to monkey patch the safe operator into a method call

Comment: Ah, I see now. Need to rest :) Thought the navigation operator was doing nothing useful there (and `public_send` would have sufficed)

Comment: Apparently safe navigation doesnt work on Classes or Modules

Comment: @WestonGanger what do you mean? It works just fine `Class&.to_s #=>"Class"`

Comment: Ex. `Array&.bad_method #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `bad_method' for Array:Class`

Comment: @WestonGanger that has nothing to do with the safe navigation operator. You explicitly stated *"I dont care about the minor behaviour differences between try and safe navigation operator"* (well that is one of the differences) I have updated my answer drastically to illustrate

Answer (score 0):

I have created a gem to solve this problem based on info from this StackOverflow answer.

[fast_try](https://github.com/westonganger/fast_try) is a simple method wrapper to the safe navigation operator.

Features / Goals:

- Utilize the safe navigation operator (&.) while improving readability
- Improve performance over other implementations such as the ActiveSupport#try method
- Do not worry about most obscure arguments / syntax limitations if they cannot be avoided. Simplicity and speed is key.
- The methods provided should behave very similarly to the safe navigation operator. If you need to retain the exact behaviour of ActiveSupport try, simply set your own custom method name(s) for FastTry.
- The only dependency is Ruby 2.3+. It does NOT require Rails /ActiveSupport anything else however it works great with it too!

In an Initializer:

```
FastTry.method_names = [:try, :custom_try, :try!]
require 'fast_try/apply'
```

Usage:

```
str.try(:upcase).try(:downcase)

# the above statement is now equivalent to using the safe navigation operator Ex.
str&.upcase&.downcase
```

Comment: It's not alias, though. It may be an implementation that behaves identically, but it's not an alias.

Comment: "should always behave just like the safe navigation operator" - there is only one test in this gem. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @SergioTulentsev is right this is not an alias just a method wrapper. Also since you noted in your gem that there are no known differences I figure it is worht mentioning that there are notable and poignant differences between the safe navigator and `try`. Please see some of these notable differences in [This Repl Spec](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/AStry-vs-and-Safe-Navigation)

Comment: The repo is open source. Its all about collaboration. Simply add a PR or issue in the repo as you deem appropriate.

Comment: @WestonGanger I am well aware of how open source works but given that your gem is a single file. I would essentially be rewriting your entire library which is not my intention nor does it allow you to showcase your own work.