# Adding time after using a safe navigation operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an object called `event`. One of the attributes is `updated_at` which is a `date time`. I want to add 15 seconds to `updated_at` to handle some tests that I'm doing.

It works when I do `event.updated_at + 15.seconds`

When testing, sometimes `event` is `nil`. So I handled it by using the safe navigator `&.` However, I'm unable to add the seconds now because I cannot chain an ordinary method call after a safe navigator operator.

So this will not work `event&.updated_at + 15.seconds`

Does anyone know how I can add time after using a safe navigator?

I guess I can do

```
if event
  event.updated_at + 15.seconds
end
```

But was looking for a better approach

Comment: `event.updated_at + 15.seconds if event` or `event.updated_at + 15.seconds unless event.nil?` is probably what you want

Comment: "But was looking for a better approach" - that's a good enough approach already.

Comment: `event&.updated_at&.send(:+, 15.seconds)`, but will not ever advice you to use it. It's completely incomprehensible and unncessary.

Comment: what about using ".try" method ? 
https://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/Object/try

Comment: try method is same as &. method ! all of these solutions are worthy !

Comment: You could also do `event && event.updated_at + 15.seconds`. If `event` is `nil`, this will evaluate to `nil`, otherwise it is the time.

Comment: safe navigation is of ruby, try is of rails ActiveSupport @ATF

Comment: and I think safe navigation is `try!` rather than `try` @ATF

Comment: @kiddorails yes I just wanted to mention the method ! And I think there were no mention of just ruby navigations !!

Comment: @ATF relax. I was just telling the difference. You say **same**, I say **similar**. Sorry for nitpicking, if it offended you.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments! All of this was helpful!

Comment: @kiddorails you are right to say `try` and `try!` are not the same thing as safe navigation [Repl Spec](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/AStry-vs-and-Safe-Navigation) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50471518/ruby-is-it-possible-to-alias-a-method-to-the-safe-navigation-operator/50472152

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use few different approaches, on your taste. But let's benchmark them!

```
n = 10_000_000

Benchmark.bm do |test|
  test.report('if:')       { n.times { nil.updated_at + 15.seconds if nil } }
  test.report('unless:')   { n.times { nil.updated_at + 15.seconds unless nil.nil? } }
  test.report('& + send:') { n.times { nil&.updated_at&.send(:+, 15.seconds) } }
  test.report('& + try:')  { n.times { nil&.updated_at.try(:+, 15.seconds) } }  
end  

#              user       system     total        real
# if:        0.390000    0.000000   0.390000   (0.392020)
# unless:    0.570000    0.000000   0.570000   (0.569032)
# & + send:  0.380000    0.000000   0.380000   (0.381654)
# & + try:   13.950000   0.000000  13.950000   (13.959887)
```

The results are in seconds. So сhoose the fastest or most attractive:)

Comment: I'm sure I wouldn't use the 3rd even if it shows slight benchmark improvement. Ultimately, the code should be understandable. If such code exists in a repository, I gape in horror on what else the repo might have in store.

Comment: @kiddorails me neither

Comment: this `nil&.updated_at&.send(:+, 15.seconds)` could be `nil&.updated_at&.+(15.seconds)` since `+` is a method. The first 2 are not the same as the others (although technically the other 2 are not the same either).