# Ruby's safe navigation operator (&.) not working as intended anymore after being in use on production code for years

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, null-check, safe-navigation-operator

I'm having this issue in production code that's been running for years without issue, where suddenly a lot of places where i use the `&.` operator is just crashing. So I'm wondering if it's not <s>just an environment variable or some kind of interpreter option</s>. It's running Ruby `2.5.9` on Rails `5.1.4`

With the following line as an example

```
s.item.tags.select { |tag| tag.name }
```

`item` is `nil`, so trying to execute this line will give me the following error

```
undefined method `tags' for nil:NilClass
```

So in theory by using the `&.` operator

```
s.item&.tags.select { |tag| tag.name }
```

I should not be getting this error but I am

```
private method `select' called for nil:NilClass
```

It seems to me like it should stop at `s.item&.` and return `nil`, but it keeps going.

If I add another `&.` it will just crash on the next one

```
s.item&.tags&.select { |tag| tag.name }.map { ... }
undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
```

and so on.

### --EDIT--

I should mention, what I'm assuming is happening is that there has never been a case where `s.item` was nil in the past so it has never crashed because of that. It seems that most of the errors were linked to that specific item being nil, probably not because of an environment variable or interpreter option.

Comment: Your edit is correct. Safe Navigation only "protects" the next call e.g. `s.item&.tags #=> nil` and then `select` is called on `nil` just like any other method chain. While there is overhead and notable differences you could use `ActiveSupport#try` instead or something similar to this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50471518/ruby-is-it-possible-to-alias-a-method-to-the-safe-navigation-operator)

Comment: Instead of chaining `&.` operators with `&.select { ... }`, `&.map { ... }`, etc. You could also use the null object pattern. Rails provides the [`none`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-none) method to help you with this. `tags = s.item&.tags || Tag.none` after that you can just use your normal `.` calls. `tags.select { ... }.map { ... }`.

Comment: There must be something wrong with your Ruby installation. In general, Ruby code should *never, ever* be able to cause a crash. It should `raise` some sort of `Exception`. The fact that it is crashing is deeply concerning.

Comment: or you could just use an empty array `[]` instead of `none` --->  `(s.item&.tags || []).select { ... }.map { ... }`

Comment: @JörgWMittag I think he might be meaning page erroring out when he says crashing

Comment: @rubyprince  `tags` will return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` and stubbing that with an `Array` is probably not a good idea.

Comment: @engineersmnky yeah, I just realized it will not work if tags is further chained with another AR scope as `[]` will not be able to handle AR scopes. `none` is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must be a data issue on your end - some new `s` records do not contain any of these relationships `items`->`tags`, instead of Ruby's safe navigation behavior changed on it's own in the same version (assuming no ruby version upgrades happen).

Safe navigation in Ruby behaves that way. Even in Ruby's official documentation that is the noted behavior:

> Note that &. skips only one next call, so for a longer chain it is necessary to add operator on each level